# How to remove glue from temporary paper shades on vinyl windows?

Tags: windows, adhesive, removal, vinyl

I put up some temporary paper shades with the stick-on backing that were positioned on the **vinyl** part of my windows.  After a good 6 months I finally needed to remove them.  However while the paper ripped off, a lot of the glue itself remained.  I tried both water and alcohol and a lot of rubbing and scraping, but the glue still remained.  The only thing that saved me was that the new shades that were put up covered the left over glue (which I accept, but it bugs me)

I have some more paper shades to remove in the nearish future and expect the same amount of left over glue.  Given that the shades are stuck to a vinyl window, what would be the best solution to remove this sort of glue?

Note that this residue is on the *vinyl* part of the frame of the window, and *not* on the glass

And I am looking for solutions that are readily available in the USA

Comment: Is it the vinyl sash or the glass that this is stuck to? It's not entirely obvious to me, and that will likely have an impact on the answers.

Comment: @FreeMan See the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a dupe of the "duplicate" close, because that is about removing adhesive goo from glass, and this one is about removing it from the vinyl frame. It is, however, a product recommendation question, which is also off-topic, so the close is appropriate even if the listed reason isn't.

Comment: @FreeMan How can you ask such a situation specific question without approving to be a product recommendation question?

Comment: There has been a lot of [discussion on Meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=product+recommendation) about that. Reading some of those may help. It may also help those who VtC as "product recommendations".

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where you are on the globe so it's hard to recommend a particular product, but there are lots of adhesive remover type of products on the market, that *should* be safe for vinyl window frames.  Here in the USA, one brand is "Goo Gone", but that's just one of likely many brands out there with similar capabilities.

Comment: GooGone would be my first answer, but I've also learned that the original WD-40 can be used for adhesive removal as well as peanut butter! One would want to check that WD-40 does not react with vinyl by testing in an unobtrusive location.

Comment: Yep, it's the "Is it safe for vinyl?" part that I'm worried about.  BTW as per my edit, I am looking for US products

Comment: @fred_dot_u Is that crunchy or smooth peanut butter?  lol   The Wd-40 is also interesting.  I still have one of the old vinyl windows that was replaced with the new ones that I could test on.  I'd hope that the chemical makeup of vinyl windows hasn't changed over the last 15 years

Comment: I sometimes use also butter or oil to remove adhesive stickers from whatever surface i need to. Maybe you can also use those tools to clean ceran cook fields (sorry, i am german)...

Answer (score -1):

If the windows are GLASS, fingernail polish REMOVER will work just fine, or acetone same thing. POLISH REMOVER is great for removing any sticker residue or glue residue from things you may purchase, as long as they are glass or ceramic in nature.

As far as the vinyl is concerned, I'm concerned that they would get damaged, if not completely destroyed! Vinyl is after all another type of plastic. And a lot of glues are gelatin or plastic based.But I know how to find out the BEST answer!

I would find out who is known for making the absolute best american-made vinyl windows. That is if you cannot determine who the manufacturer of your vinyl windows are. Also, it would help to have an approximate as to the age of your vinyl windows as well.

Comment: Random ALL caps words make this SEEM like a SPAM post, but there isn't a LINK to anything, SO I guess it's not. The last paragraph is OUT of the blue and has nothing AT ALL to do with the QUESTION at hand, so it should be [EDIT]ED out of your answer. Please take the [tour] so you can LEARN how things work HERE at [diy.se], since it's a little DIFFERENT than at other SITES. (See, hard to read, isn't it. Fix the all caps while you're editing out that last paragraph.)